# Release License from ArcGIS License Administrator

Tags: arcgis-license-manager, arcgis-10.5

I want to release two machines using my Network Analyst extension from license server administrator. The problem is that those two machines no longer exists on our domain and it is impossible to release license from that machine itself. The machines are listed on Borrowed tab on the license server administrator but not on checkedOut tab. What can I do about this issue?

Comment: How long were they borrowed for and how long is remaining? It might be easier to just wait. If it were easy to release borrowed licenses then dodgy operators might be tempted to 'double dip' their licenses.

Comment: Actually it borrowed for 6500 days. So its not an option.

Comment: If you contact ESRI they can do it.

Comment: Have a read of https://geonet.esri.com/thread/51424, apparently if you set the time 6501 days ahead it will release then set the time back. Setting the time/date could do nasty things with your network though so make sure you get it back to your DNS datetime quickly.

Comment: We dont have internet connection on our domain and they have to come here to do the releasing which will take time. I want to release the license today itself because we have some urgent tasks to complete.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson. here is the real problem. The ESRI team done the setup for ArcGIS environment here. They set the borrowing time to 65000 days which is up to 2194. And maximum time we can set on windows server 2008 is up to 2099. So what i should do to obtain the licenses.

Comment: You have this question tagged with ArcGIS 10.0, which was retired more than 15 months ago. Do you have current maintenance? Esri Customer Service should be the first and second places to go for licensing issues.